# How to set or remove ngrok authentication request?

Tags: webserver, authentication, localhost, header

I have set up `ngrok` and ran it by pointing it towards nothing. But when I make a request to the link provided by `ngrok`, I am being asked for authentication.

I tried my username and password of computer, of the ID I registered ngrok with and both of them didn't work.

I couldn't find any proper information as to how to deal with this on their official docs. [Client API Ngrox authentication](https://ngrok.com/docs#client-api-base) isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3):

1. Log in to [ngrok dashboard](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth/your-authtoken)
2. Get the console commands from there - check attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvS0F.png)
3. There is also an option to revoke the auth token directly from the dashboard.

Comment: You are not explaining how to remove the basic auth.

Answer (score 3):

`ngrok authtoken ""` worked for me. Otherwise find your ngrok.yml file and just remove it manually.

```
Linux: "~/.config/ngrok/ngrok.yml"
MacOS (Darwin): "~/Library/Application Support/ngrok/ngrok.yml"
Windows: "%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\ngrok\ngrok.yml"
```